# I'm having issues getting a basic MOSFET switch to work

Tags: mosfet, switches, raspberry-pi

I read this:  [Using MOSFET as switch](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/213914/using-mosfet-as-switch)

And this: http://bildr.org/2012/03/rfp30n06le-arduino/

This is my wiring(G, D, S are Gate Drain and Source): 
[image]

It's not working.  The MOSFET is of the correct type, I don't have the specs on it on hand, but I know for sure that it is the correct type of MOSFET.

I've also seen in diagrams there is a resistor that would connect GPIO directly to Pi-Ground, but adding that did not fix it either.

How does one do a MOSFET switch?

Comment: This small fruit happens to be running a server that hosts a web interface, and its PWM is working great.  I had all of this functioning before, but I knocked out a few cords, and I haven't been able to get it back.

Comment: -1 without the part number of the MOSFET, no, you cannot know that it is the correct type.  You've presented no evidence that it is even an N-channel device, let alone that it has a sufficiently low threshold voltage for 3.3v drive.

Comment: Just assume it was, is this the correct wiring?

Comment: Found the mfg: IRLB8721PBF

https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/irlb8721pbf.pdf

Comment: There's no way that FET will drive with only 3.3V

Comment: Reread the specs.  It works

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use a FET with a threshod of of 2~4V on a 3.3V swing. It must be a logic level FET 1V Vgs(th)  i.e. gate voltage >=3x threshold.

With Drain low side switch to 0V  it must be an  Nch Logic Level FET rated for > 5x actual load current for good cool results.

The https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/General/RFP30N06LE.pdf is good for 5V but **marginal** for 3.3V as Vgs(th) is 1~2V so you need 3~6V minimum.

Comment: It is definitely not the MOSFET.  It was working when my friend helped me build it a month ago, the cords got jumbled out, and I'm trying to put it back together.

Right now, I'm thinking my breadboard my just be really crappy.

Comment: But if you're saying the wiring is correct, that definitely helps me narrow down the issue.

Comment: mosfets can die instantly, and are sensitive to static, much less "jumbled out" connections...

Comment: I just coerced my friend to come over, and, as it turns out... super lame... it was my weak bread board.  He told me he doesn't trust breadboards, which I now understand.  We got everything working, and, while it is better to have a resistor connecting G and S, it working fine without it.

Comment: breadboard contacts are fine if you know the limits of wire size similar to 1/4W resistor lead size.

Comment: I guess your FET is marginally OK then.

Comment: you don't need a resistor except to get higher switching frequency, but that also takes a higher drive voltage that you can provide. the internal resistance of your raspi should be plenty to "pull the gate closed" at PWM frequencies...

Comment: pulling the gate closed depends on device tolerances. of Vgs/Vgs(th) which controls RdsOn from kOhm range at Threshold.. This is why I said 3x Vgs(th) for adequate margin.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to post this here to help other absolute beginners like me.  The circuit above is correct and imperfect. But if it isn't working, here are some cases to check:

My issue was the breadboard being finicky.  If a single connection point on a breadboard is at the whim of chance (as in you have to wiggle it a bit to get a connection), then that's the chance you won't have a working circuit.  Those chances compile too.

But also, if you're trying to get a circuit like this working, it is important to read the answer above: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/323022/87434 about getting the right MOSFET.  What matters most in a scenario like this is getting an N-Channel MOSFET with the minimum threshold being below 3.3V

Finally, it is good practice to have a resistor connecting the Gate and Source.  I'll update this later with the correct resistor type (once I've found it).  I believe it's because connecting these helps ensure that the MOSFET defaults to off if something goes awry.