# Introducing a MOSFET to a circuit

Tags: mosfet, raspberry-pi

I have ordered the following [MOSFET](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/1009957/ISC/IRLB8721.html) from aliexpress, ran some checks on it and it seems fine.

I read in the above [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/213914/using-mosfet-as-switch) (which fits my desired circuit) that "most MOSFETs won't work with an RPi".
It seems though that the parameters for my MOSFET are find, namely a low enough Vgs(th).

I would like to get a second opinion on  that.
Thanks.

Comment: Introducing it.... "MOSFET, meet circuit. Circuit, MOSFET."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more relevant specification than Vgs(th) is the voltage or voltages at which Rds(on) is specified.

In the case of the MOSFET you have, it is only guaranteed with 10V Vgs, which is much more than a Raspberry Pi outputs (3.3V nominal for high).

MOSFETs which are specified for Rds(on) with low Vgs (especially those specified for 1.8, 2.5 or 3V) have two general characteristics:

1. Vds(max) is not very high, usually tens of volts
2. Unpleasant packaging for hobbyists (SMT almost exclusively)

However to answer your specific question, the MOSFET you have will indeed "work" when driven with a Raspberry Pi output, if by "work" you mean that the MOSFET will conduct more than a few tens of microamperes. Note the 25uA figure which determines Vgs(th) for this part. How much more will vary from part to part, but it is most unlikely to be satisfactory for an application requiring a TO-220 low Rds(on) MOSFET.

Vgs(th) is better thought of as the Vgs at which the MOSFET is mostly "off" (where it just begins to conduct) and that is not the Vgs at which the MOSFET is mostly "on".

Comment: Then would it be correct to say that the MOSFET will conduct on my RPi 3.3V but it will consume a lot of power on its own making my main appliance (a fan) weaker?

Comment: Not quite. It may drop a lot of voltage, reducing the voltage across the load (and in this case, making the fan weaker). The total power would be less the higher the MOSFET resistance gets, *and* more of that power gets dissipated by the MOSFET with a maximum when it equals the load resistance. Ideally we want the MOSFET to be either extreme high resistance (little current flows so total power is negligible) or very low (almost all voltage is across the load, so the MOSFET runs cool). If the load is fixed resistance (not quite true for a fan) then the current is V/(Rload + RMOSFET).

Comment: So the MOSFET power dissipation is I^2*RMOSFET = V^2*RMOSFET/(Rload+RMOSFET)^2 which is a quadratic with a maxima at Rload = RMOSFET = Rx, where PMOSFET = V^2/4Rx. So if your load is 1 ohm, and voltage is 12V, if the MOSFET is 1 ohm, the fan sees 6V (and runs much more slowly) and the MOSFET sees 6V (and dissipates 144/4 = 36W (a lot). But if the MOSFET Rds(on) with 10V drive is 0.0087 ohm the MOSFET will only dissipate 1.2W, and only a small heat sink would be required. The load would see 99% of of the 12V and would consume 141W. Note the two are already add up to bit less than 144W.

Comment: Ok I understand it a lot better now.
Thank you for your time and effort!

Answer (score 1):

The part is a copy of an [Infineon IRLB8721PbF](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IRLB8721-DataSheet-v01_01-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153566056732591). The Infineon data sheet provides more specification than the AliExpress one.

The Infineon specification for Rdson = 8.7 milli-ohm at 10V VGS and Rdson = 16 milli-ohm at 4.5V VGS.

Will it work at 3.3V?

The chart in Figure 12 on page 6 shows that Rdson at 3.3V is very high. Any thing below 4.0 volts is insufficient.

I have not used a Raspberry PI, so if the output voltage will source 5 volts then the MOSFET will work provided that the AliExpress copy is well done.

If the output of the Raspberry PI is 3.3 volts, then the MOSFET will not work.

[image]

Comment: Then would it be correct to say that the MOSFET will conduct on my RPi 3.3V but it will consume a lot of power on its own making my main appliance (a fan) weaker? How do you suggest that I measure the R_DS for the 3.3V of the RPi? Will a simple multimeter do the work?